# How to automatically delete file from runtime in Yii2 that isn't being used for current runtime?

Tags: php, yii2

There are so many files created for runtime but may or may not be used for present tasks that occupies unneccessary space. If there's any way to do this either by fiddling around Yii2's own setings or by any other means, please specify those as much as you can?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the folder contents. Yii will create the necessary files again.